# GridDB: 10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE error while trying to connect to GridDB with DBVisualizer using the gridstore-jdbc JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, griddb, dbvisualizer

I have used DBVisualizer to add a Custom Driver via the Driver manager.

I'm following the instructions located [here](https://docs.griddb.net/jdbcdriver/overview/)

I added the gridstore-jdbc.jar file to the custom driver. I select the Driver Class as com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver

The default JDBC URL Format in the template for DBVisualizer is as follows:

`jdbc:<change>://${Server|localhost}${Port|1234||prefix=: }`

And I have changed it to:

`jdbc:gs://${Server|localhost}${Port|1234||prefix=: }`

In the Connection entry in DbVisualizer, I've selected my custom driver, set my server to localhost and port to 10001. I've also added the default Database Userid and Password as provided in the GridDB instructions. Database Type has been set to Auto Detect (Generic)

With the above entered, I tried to connect and got the following error:

> An error occurred while establishing the connection:
>
> Long Message:
> [10054:TXN_CLIENT_VERSION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE] (connectClientVersion=-9, serverVersion=15) (address=127.0.0.1:10001, partitionId=0)
>
> Details:
> Type: java.sql.SQLException
> Error Code: 10054
> SQL State: 00

There are several JDBC formats mentioned in the GridDB documentation and I've seen this one:

`jdbc:gs://(multicastAddress):(portNo)/(clusterName)/(databaseName)`

I did not add clustername/databasename to the entry in DBVisualizer as I am not sure that I need it and not sure how to do that. I am not sure that's the problem either because the error mentions client version and I can see that it's reaching out to the correct address and port.

Is the connection string the problem or is something else afoot?